# Is it too late to save this leafless stub?

Tags: plant-care

Here's what I have:

[image]

The trunk on the left has been dead for a long time (dried brown). It is old. The trunk on the right (green) was left alone over winter and it rained a lot. When I came back from travels, the leaves were rotting (too much water and cold I'm guessing?).

The top of the little trunk is cut. I cut it because it was dying/rotting dark brown material, just like the leaves that were in top.

Can it be saved?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's dead. But the cost of waiting a little while is not big. Maybe just stick it in a medium lighted area, water it when it gets dry, and hope.  If it's going to live it will show you something soon. Otherwise, replant.

Comment: @BobaFit waiting worked! (See answer)

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It had stubs at the bottom, and they turned out to be sprouts. With some patience, and being sure not to overwater, it sprung back!

[image]